# PHP Ignore error and keep processing

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

```
class MyClass {

    public function __construct(){
    }

    private function makeError(){
        return sp('ABC'); // sp is undefined function
    }

    private function printMe(){
        echo "PRINT ME";
    }

    public function run(){

        try {
            $t = $this->makeError();

        }catch(Exception $e){
        }

        $this->printMe();       
    }
}

$t = new MyClass();
$t->run();
```

If run above code, an error occur because sp() is not defined function.

But I'd like to ignore the error and run printMe method.

How should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: What type of error does this throw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use function_exist()

```
class MyClass {

    public function __construct(){
    }

    private function makeError(){
        if(!function_exist('sp')){
             throw new Exception();
        }else{
             return sp('ABC'); // sp is undefined function
        }
    }

    private function printMe(){
        echo "PRINT ME";
    }

    public function run(){

        try {
            $t = $this->makeError();

        }catch(Exception $e){
        }

        $this->printMe();       
    }
}
```

you can't catch the fact that it does'n exist because it's a fatal error

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. It's a fatal error, not an exception.
Therefore it cannot be catched.

In this very instance you can *eschew causing the error* however with:

```
if (function_exists("sp")) {
     return sp('ABC'); // sp is undefined function
}
```

Likewise you could wrap your `$this->makeError();` call with that test. But that would mean handling another methods interna. And anyway, that would just avoid that super specific edge case.

Answer (score 0):

As answered already, this is a fatal error: you can't use your own error handler, the best would be to test if the function is available with [function_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php).

You may also be able to use somme buffering to do some tricks as explained in this SO anwser: [set_error_handler Isn't Working How I Want It To Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621/set-error-handler-isnt-working-how-i-want-it-to-work#36705)